# Programmatically setting up a static website using Amazon S3 and Route 53 APIs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Assume I already have purchased a domain example.com with IP address 203.0.113.2. Using C# and the The Amazon Web Services SDK for .NET 2.0.2.2, I'd like to create a static website using a custom domain using Amazon S3 and Route 53. The manual process is described in the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

When trying to create an alias, I get an exception with the message:

```
Invalid XML ; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'AliasTarget'.
One of '{"https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-12-12/":ResourceRecords}' is expected.
```

First, I created or updated a bucket (e.g. "example.com") in Amazon S3. If it already existed, content is deleted.

```
using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest1))
{
    if (!S3BucketExists(name, client))
    {
        client.PutBucket(new PutBucketRequest
        {
            BucketName = name,
            BucketRegion = S3Region.USW1,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var request = new ListObjectsRequest
        {
            BucketName = name
        };
        var objects = client.ListObjects(request).S3Objects;
        foreach (var o in objects)
        {
            client.DeleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = name,
                Key = o.Key
            });
        }
        client.PutACL(new PutACLRequest
        {
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead, 
            BucketName = name
        });
    }

    client.PutBucketWebsite(new PutBucketWebsiteRequest
    {
        BucketName = name,
        WebsiteConfiguration = new WebsiteConfiguration
        {
            ErrorDocument = "404.html",
            IndexDocumentSuffix = "index.html"
        }
    });

    CreateObject(name, client, "index.html", "text/html", "<p>The site is under maintenance</p>");
    CreateObject(name, client, "404.html", "text/html", "<p>Not Found</p>");
}
```

S3BucketExists returns whether a bucket exist or not, and CreateObject creates a simple page and uploads it to the bucket.  Its omitted for brevity sake. I'm able to connect to the S3 hosted site without any problems.

Then I use the Route 53 API to update an existing hosted zone or create one for "example.com". All resources, except for the SOA and NS entries are deleted.

```
using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonRoute53Client())
{
    var hostedZone = FindHostedZoneByName(client, domainName);
    if (hostedZone != null)
    {
        var resourceRecordSets = client.ListResourceRecordSets(new ListResourceRecordSetsRequest
        {
            HostedZoneId = hostedZone.Id,
        });

        bool hasElements = false;
        var request1 = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest
        {
            HostedZoneId = hostedZone.Id,
            ChangeBatch = new ChangeBatch
            {
                Changes = new List<Change>()
            }
        };
        foreach (var resourceRecordSet in resourceRecordSets.ResourceRecordSets)
        {
            switch (resourceRecordSet.Type)
            {
                case "SOA":
                case "NS":
                    continue;
            }

            var change = new Change
            {
                Action = "DELETE",
                ResourceRecordSet = resourceRecordSet
            };
            request1.ChangeBatch.Changes.Add(change);
            hasElements = true;
        }

        if (hasElements)
        {
            var response = client.ChangeResourceRecordSets(request1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hostedZone = CreateHostedZone(client, domainName);
    }

    var hostedZoneId = hostedZone.Id;
    var request = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest
    {
        HostedZoneId = hostedZoneId,
        ChangeBatch = new ChangeBatch
        {
            Changes = new List<Change>
            {
                new Change
                {
                    Action = ChangeAction.CREATE,
                    ResourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet
                    {
                        Name = GetQualifiedName(domainName),
                        Type = RRType.A,
                        TTL = 300,
                        AliasTarget = new AliasTarget()
                        {
                            HostedZoneId = "Z2F56UZL2M1ACD",
                            DNSName = "s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.",
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    };
    client.ChangeResourceRecordSets(request);
}
```

The hosted zone id ("Z2F56UZL2M1ACD") and DNS names ("s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.") are public knowledge and [documented on Amazon's website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).

The call to ChangeResourceRecordSets throws the exception. I created an empty ResourceRecords list, with a A record of "203.0.113.2", but have not had any luck creating an alias.

That said, I can manually create the alias to the Amazon S3 site afterwards using the "Route 53 Management Console".  I'm sure it's something small I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-reading the documentation, it turns out that one cannot specify the TTL when specifying an alias.  The following change works. Replace the code that creates an instance of `ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest` to the following:

```
var request = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest
{
    HostedZoneId = hostedZoneId,
    ChangeBatch = new ChangeBatch
    {
        Changes = new List<Change>
        {
            new Change
            {
                Action = ChangeAction.CREATE,
                ResourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet
                {
                    Name = GetQualifiedName(domainName),
                    Type = RRType.A,
                    AliasTarget = new AliasTarget
                    {
                        HostedZoneId = "Z2F56UZL2M1ACD",
                        DNSName = "s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.",
                        EvaluateTargetHealth = false,
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    }
};
```

The difference was evident when the output produced by [System.Net tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was compared to the request specified in the [Amazon example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowToAliasRRS.html).